# What Happens if you Instantiate an Object Whose Class Has No Constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I just realize I've been doing that and it seems like the objects' properties are still being set when I use

```
object->set($property, $value);
```

What is the expected behavior in this situation?

Comment: What exactly is the situation here? Constructor are optional and are used to perform operations that you want when any object are instantiated. If your class has no constructor it would simply not be called. Any other method would work..

Comment: I see. This seems really obvious now. I had used a constructor for every other class but this one and I was surprised it worked. Escpecially because I called it with "$obj_var = new myClass($name)" and I thought a fatal error would be caused by calling it the $name variable if I have no constructor to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object->set($property, $value);
```

set is just an method of the object's object here, probably you are referring to setter method. which takes two arguments and pass it to the class property. the behavior of setting the class depends on the code of set method, there are some benefits of using this method.

there are two ways for storing the data in a class, one way is to directly assign the values to class property for example

```
class Foo {
    public $a;
    public $b;
}
```

if you need to assign the values to the class property you would do like.

```
$object = new Foo();
$object->a = 'hello';
$object->b = 'world';
```

now the class property $a will contain the value hello and the class property $b will contain the value world, however there is a problem to this approach, we can never tell the user what type of data should come in. if we need to store only integers in $a there is no way we can do that. to overcome this you can use a setter meth, wherein we declare the class property as protected or private, and set the value through a class method.

```
class Foo {
    protected $a;
    protected $b;

   public function set($a) {
       //you can validate the data here before assigning.
       $this->a = $a;
   }
}
```

you can simply google about getter and setter method and get more information.

```
Class Constructor
```

class constructor is nothing but an method which is invoked automatically when you instantiate an object. consider that you want to instantiate an object by forcing the user to provide the user id first. or may be you want to do some useful calculation before other methods are called. this is where class constructor comes into picture. consider the below example

```
class Bar {

    protected $userId;    

    public function __construct($userId) {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        //any more code execution that needs to be done while instantiating the class can be placed here
    }
}
```

so when you instantiate the object

```
$object = new Bar();
```

this will result into error. since you haven't provided the userId. so the correct way is.

```
$object = new Bar(1);
```

now the class property `$userId` will hold the value one upon the instantiation of the object.

hope this helps you.

Comment: I see. I was thinking that you had to have a constructor but I guess you don't. That makes sense. But, on a different subject, how can your public function set($a) have only one argument? You need to know which property to set and what value to set it to.

Comment: key, values combination are needed in array, and that example is probably using array. for example in your class property you can declare `protected $_data = array()` and you assign it through setter method like this `public function set($key, $value) { $this->{$key} = $value }` it depends on what you want to do. and also remember a class with code `class A { }` is a valid class, notice that it does not have any property or constructor or any method defined.

Comment: here is an excellent tutorial by nettuts which explains object oriented php for beginners http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/

Comment: I might mark your answer accepted, but I still want to know why you have set($a). I guess it is an example of a class with only one externally-settable property? By the way, if you want a slightly more complex OOP question, see my new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511859/how-to-handle-inheritance-of-a-function-with-many-parameters

Comment: yes, that is just an example, in my later comment i have explained about using two arguments for set method. you can set as many argument as you want, one, two, three or more. just declare the number of argument in your function and decide what to do with it, i used one argument in the example because i am using the class property as a variable not as an array. since we have already declared class property then only thing we need is it's value. so one argument. if you want both the class property and the value to be set then you need to do that with array. as explained above